# Aliases for event bus $emit

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, event-bus

I would like to create aliases for the commonly used event bus methods `$emit`, `$on`, etc...

so that I could reference the event bus object like so: `EventBus.publish(...)`

I tried:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue()

export const publish = EventBus.$emit
export const subscribe = EventBus.$on
```

and then:

`import * as EventBus from '@/utils/eventBus.js'`

but i'm getting **$emit is not a function**

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: I would try `const publish = EventBus.$emit.bind(EventBus)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you bind to the object otherwise the method won't work:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue()

export const publish = EventBus.$emit.bind(EventBus)
export const subscribe = EventBus.$on.bind(EventBus)
export const unsubscribe = EventBus.$off.bind(EventBus)
```

or more explicitly:

```js
export function publish(name, ...args) {
  EventBus.$emit(name, ...args)
}

export function subscribe(name, fn) {
  EventBus.$on(name, fn)
}

export function unsubscribe(name, fn) {
  EventBus.$off(name, fn)
}
```

You import it like this:

```js
import * as EventBus from './eventBus.js'

EventBus.subscribe('event', handler)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried `bind` but most probably messed it up somewhere else :) Thank you